# can "auto function()" have several types of return inside the function body?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I am having problem with the code below,it generate errors and I believe is because apparently "auto" can't handle several types of return based on conditions.
Is that the case or something else is wrong with my code?
Also if what I am trying to do is not possible this way, it is possible in any other way?

```
auto Game_Manager::getMember(string s)
{
    if (s == "rows")return rows; // return unsigned
    else if (s == "columns")return columns; // return unsigned
    else if (s == "p1")return p1; //return string
    else if (s == "p2")return p2; //return string
    else cout << "\n\nERROR!!! Invalid argument for getMember()\n\n" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: No, because there is no type which `auto` can be replaced by

Comment: you need a tagged union (boost variant)

Comment: Where would you call this function?

Comment: @BryanChen Game_Manager collect the data needed for starting the game. I am using this function to retrieve private members of the class Game_Manager so that I can pass it to other classes,like the Board class that needs it to generate the board

Comment: @Eric inside the loop that runs the game,to retrive useful data without storing them in int main()

Comment: Why do you need `getMember("columns")` and not `getColumns()`?

Comment: @MarcusAseth: In what world do you think that `getMember("p1")` is more maintainable than `getPlayer(1)` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I am a begginner and I am experimenting both ways,to see myself benefit and drawbacks :)

Comment: @Eric : the starting idea was "what if I have 20 variables?! Do I need to declare and implement 20 functions to get each one?Wouldn't the header become too long and hard to read? I'm trying to figure out the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys :) Also forgive me this off topic,but since I am new to Stackoverflow,it is common to thanks or is only about question and answers? I need to know for future reference :P

Comment: The header could be as short as `inline int getColumns() { return columns; }`, assuming you need to hide the fields in the first place. That's not really any different to the length of the `getMember` function you'd end up writing

Comment: I was watching this video https://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU?t=2m54s and if you listen from 2:54 to 3:14 he says "so now all function return type for example can be deduced" (talking about C++14). It mean what I was trying to do can be achieved with C++14 or I misunderstood the meaning of that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` means *"work out the type for me"*, not *"accept any type"*. There is no (builtin) type that this function can be declared as, therefore `auto` is not valid

Answer (score 2):

Here's the rule of interest (from section 7.1.6.4 of the Standard)

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has multiple `return` statements, the return type is deduced for each `return` statement. **If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed.**

So, all return statements must have the same type.